# Difference between Object.save() and object.update ebean ORM (in Playframework)

Tags: orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

What is the difference between Object.save() or object.update() in ebean ORM for example used in Playframwork 2.5.9 ?

Answer (score 2):

save() ... will perform an insert or an update based on the bean state.

update() ... will perform an update (regardless of the bean state).

We can use update() to perform "stateless updates" (updates that don't have a prior fetch). That is, we can just new up a bean, set some properties and call update().

Comment: i tried a save() in addUpdate method, if there is new object, so an add operation save is not working because id is null... auto-increment is not used as insert() command